# Is is possible to convert a char with %s conversion specifier

Tags: c

```
char c;
scanf("%s",&c);
```

Is this correct or wrong ? What happening exactly when typing `EOF` character in stdin ?

I know there is something like in SO but I cannot find it ?

---

I already know the **exact right form** which should be:

```
scanf("%hhd",&c);
```

Comment: No wrong! Read documentation! `scanf("%c",&c)`

Comment: I have found this via google https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Well, it will work perfectly fine if the user just presses return, without providing any other character. :o)

Comment: @xing that's the reason of this question is it possible or not?

Comment: @MatteoItalia No it won't. That results in at least 2 chars: `\n` and `\0`

Comment: @PCLuddite what about using `EOF` character I think in this case it is possible or ?

Comment: @PCLuddite: nope, `%s` stops at the first whitespace character, which is not extracted; you are confusing it with the semantics of `fgets`.

Comment: (OTOH, thinking about it, `%s` discards all whitespace before starting to extract, so probably it's actually impossible to get it to extract zero characters, except maybe on EOF, but in that case the return value will probably be zero and the string is left untouched)

Comment: @MatteoItalia it will skip the newline. As the only possible one is typing EOF character

Comment: The  only way for that is entering an empty string. but the type of argument can be considered as character of array this is what I want to know so I can be sure it is valid.

Comment: @Sabrina: well in that case `c` will be left untouched (=not even set to zero) and `scanf` will return 0.

Comment: No it will be an emtpy string and will be filled with `\0` with value 0 probably.

Comment: In the case that you use " char c[100]; ", it would be right.

Comment: @SaeedTalaee welcome to C language.

Comment: @Sabrina: nope, the whitespace is discarded, EOF is encountered, and the extraction of characters for `%s` doesn't even begin; that's quite clear if you read in the standard how `scanf` is supposed to work. You can also check it yourself: http://ideone.com/NYp5F4 (where stdin is a few spaces and newlines); `ch` is left untouched after the `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not correct.

While it might appear that sending the address to the char (`&c`) would be equivalent, it is not the same as a "string."

Of course, C doesn't really have a string type; instead, we find an abstraction in the standard library string and printf style functions that use the convention of a character pointer to a set of bytes with a null byte (null terminator) at the end of the string.

If you tell `scanf` to read into a `"%s"` and then provide a `char &`, the allocation will only be for one byte.  Even if the input is only a single byte, it will be null-terminated (an extra byte appended to the end), automatically causing a buffer overflow.

Comment: There will be no allocation at all even with EOF.

Comment: I was referring to the single byte allocated either on the stack for the local variable `c`.  I'm not talking about `scanf` allocating anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. You can't put a string in a `char`. This is undefined behavior and will probably result in memory stomping.

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

is how you put take a `char` from `scanf`.

Better yet, avoid `scanf()` entirely and use `getchar()`:

```
int c = getchar();
```

Just be aware of the return type.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly wrong to use `char c;scanf("%s",&c).`. Format specifier `"%s"` reads in a sequence of non-white-space characters and appends a `'\0'` at the end (cf. [cppreference concerning scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)). So it will most likely exceed the memory provided by a single character `char c` (unless the user just presses return or ctrl-d).

Use `char c;scanf("%c",&c).` instead.